# Display live log in HTA window

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am working on an application for a liquid handling robot for which I would like to display an HTA window during the run which constantly updates to tell the user or casual observer what stage of the process it is at. The software for the robot is basically a GUI for vbScript with a few knobs and can run vbScript and executables during a run. I can use vbScript to create a timestamped file and append it during the run, but I would like to be able to render this in real time in a browser window.
Initially I thought of simply saving several versions of a template HTA window for each stage and opening them from the software but I can't seem to find any code that will close the currently open window before opening a new one.
The alternative I thought might be to simply write a new text file at each stage and have the HTA display the update on an If FileExists basis, but again I cant find any code that will make the HTA window check frequently (but doesn't also use up all the CPU or bring up warnings that it might crash the browser) and "repaints" the window.
I am only personally a little familiar with vbScript and HTML/CSS but if any workable solutions involve JavaScript or anything else I'm willing to have a go!

Any help much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the innerhtml or outerhtml of the element you want to change.

```
        HotKeyList.InnerHTML = "<table id=thotkeylist>" & headrow & TableVar & "</table>"

<span id=HotKeyList>

</span>
```

Comment: Also the IE window object has a timer. See setInterval Method.